# AES-256-GCM using GnuPG

Tags: aes, gnupg

Is there a way to encrypt files with AES 256 in the authenticated GCM mode using GPG?

I don't see GCM in supported cipher modes. It seems that the GPG uses only one mode (its own modification of CFB), although libgcrypt supports GCM.

Edit:

GnuPG relies on Modification Detection Code (MDC) based on SHA-1 for authentication. It's unclear how the authentication performance of the MDC compares with the HMAC in GCM.

Comment: _PGP_ uses a modified CFB, not CBC. Since (original) GPG is designed to be compatible with other PGP programs, it follows the standard.

Comment: My bad, I meant CFB (they are very similar modes). Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not in version 2.2.20 of GnuPG.

Comment: How good an alternative is "encrypt and sign" to AEAD? And what if I externally MAC the encrypted file using a different program?

Comment: Depends on what your goal is. If you want to communicate with someone without everybody knowing the message is from you, then "sign, then encrypt" is better.

Comment: GPG uses Sym. Encrypted Integrity Protected Data Packet, and Modification Detection Code (MDC) apparently SHA-1. They provide some protection against bit rot and tampering. Wouldn't that be a good replacement for MAC in GCM?

Comment: @eli That seems like a better question for [crypto.se]

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG is an ancient design that wasn't designed from the ground up to do authenticated encryption properly. This is, for example, [one of the causes of the Efail vulnerabilities](https://blog.hboeck.de/archives/893-efail-Outdated-Crypto-Standards-are-to-blame.html). GnuPG will output the whole plaintext for forged messages to stdout before checking its message digest code.

If you're looking for a commandline file encryption tool that follows modern best practices, [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age) seems to be the up and comer right now. It uses ChaCha20-Poly1305, though, not AES-GCM as you're asking.

If you need public key signatures, [signify](https://github.com/aperezdc/signify) is a much recommended newer tool.

Comment: Yes, ChaCha via Age doesn't enjoy hardware acceleration. Any alternative using libsodium? What if I use Python bindings and write my own encryption script calling libsodium? I doesn't see any program making libsodium usable like GPG.

Comment: Alternatively, I could write a script to do AES with GPG and MAC SHA256 using another program.